# Only offer TFS 2010 build for testing when they have a certain build quality

Tags: tfsbuild, build-automation, microsoft-test-manager

When a nightly build is done with TFS 2010 team build, the build number is automatically registered in Test Manager to be picked up by testers to start testing on. But I need to control the version numbers that are listed in Test Manager to be used for manual testing. Not all builds should end up in the list, only the builds with certain build qualities.

How do I keep the available build number list in Test Manager clean, not listing all builds that are performed, but only listing the builds I assign a certain build quality?

Comment: I believe that Test Manager has a filter on the builds it chooses. I believe you can filter by build quality.

Comment: I have no filter choosen but still I only see those builds with "Passed" (green button) status. It doesn't metter which quality you choose, Test Manager just shows "passed" builds, without a single error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the "Plan" menu and choose "Properties". Under "Run Settings", there's a section for "Builds". It includes "Filter for builds". If you pull that down, you'll see you can choose which build definition to look at, as well as which build quality.

Comment: This is definately what I was looking for. John, thank you very much for your help!